# custom UINavigationBar background in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I have a need to use a custom background for the `UINavigationBar` in a `MFMailComposeViewController`. Previously I was using a category on `UINavigationBar` to achieve this throughout my app, but Apple specifically requests that you do not do this. Additionally this may or may not work in future versions of iOS that are currently under NDA.

I am now using a subclass of `UINavigationBar` to achieve the look I'm after in the rest of the app, but I can't see any way to use this with the `MFMailComposeViewController`. Any ideas?

Note: I'm aware of methods to do this in a future version of iOS, but this needs to be built against a current version (4.3) of the SDK.

Comment: Check my answer regarding `object_setClass` below. That seems likely to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran across this -- you can dynamically inject the class a view controller uses using `object_setClass`.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

object_setClass(mailController.navigationBar, [YourNavigationBarSubClass class]);
```

Comment: It feels a bit dangerous, but this does actually work and holds up under testing on all versions of iOS I have access to. One thing to note is that the subclass must not have any ivars.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the nav bar's titleView with a custom view using the code below. Expanding upon this idea, you *may* be able to resize the titleView to cover the entire navigation bar and use a custom background in that to simulate a custom navbar background.

The only possible sticky part I can think of is that you need to make sure the titleView sits behind the buttons in the toolbar.

Once you have your MFMailComposerViewController reference, here is the code to customize the titleView:

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(//set size to navbar size)];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage://your custom image ]];

controller.topViewController.navigationItem.titleView = backgroundView ;
[controller release];
```

Comment: Neat idea - it didn't actually work for me as the background behind the buttons was wrong, but you get an upvote for creativity!

Answer (score 1):

The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application.

check apple reference for more info...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

but we can customizable the mail composition as given oin the above answer....

Comment: This is true, but I've never had a problem with apps being rejected because of this, and I believe it creates a better experience.

Comment: The interface _is_ customizable. Whether Apple will reject such customizations is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

After some hacking and testing, still not manage to customize the button. But this is the closest I can get, by setting the tint color of mail controller.

Try accessing them through `mailController.navigationBar.items,` which is an array of the bar items.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
mailController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
```

Comment: I can customize the buttons without a problem. It is the background that I need to customize.

Answer (score 0):

Although it would be nice to get more control over the appearance, I don't think there is a clean method.  When you cant change it...hide it:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor]};
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
```